# Is thread (parallel computing in c++) incompatible with optimization levels (gcc)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, parallel-processing, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to learn how to use multithreading and then I made a code (see below). As expected the **parallel** function takes **2.6s** while the **non-parallel** takes **6.4s**.

Then I tried to modify the compilation by use of the optimization -O3 available at gcc. With that the **non-parallel** function took **0s** and the **parallel** one took **2s**! Showing that -O3 didn't act on the parallel function.

Why didn't the optimization level worked with the thread?? Is there some fundamental problem? Did I just make something wrong?

Follows the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

#define N 1E8
#define num_sum std::thread::hardware_concurrency()

void fS(void){
    double sum;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        sum += sin(i*0.1);
    }
//  cout << endl << sum << endl;    
    return;
}

void fS_N(vector<double>& sum,int j){
    int i;

    int imin,imax,intervalo;
        intervalo = N/num_sum;
        imin = j*intervalo;
        imax = (j+1)*intervalo;

    for(i=imin;i<imax;i++){
        sum[j] += sin(i*0.1);
    }   
    return;
}

int main(){
    clock_t t;

    cout << "# disponiveis de nos/cpu: " << num_sum << endl;

    //no parallel
    t = clock();
    fS();
    t = clock()-t;
    cout << "\n Time (no parallel):";
    cout << ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;     

    //parallel
    t = clock();    
    vector<thread> allsum;
    vector<double> Svalue(num_sum,0.);
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j<num_sum; j++){
        allsum.push_back(thread (fS_N, ref(Svalue),j) );
    }

    for(auto &t : allsum){
        t.join();
    }

    double Soma=0.;
    for (j=0;j<num_sum;j++){
        Soma += Svalue[j];
    }
//  cout << Soma << endl;
    t = clock()-t;
    cout << "\n Time (parallel):";
    cout << ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;     

return 0;
}
```

Comment: When anything takes 0s you should get suspicious. Your benchmark is invalid.

Comment: Well, that 0s means something like 10^-5. (I could modify the program to generate it explicitly, but it's not the point)

Comment: In the `fS()` function you compute a sum that is never used. The optimizer is smart enough to not compute values that are not used.

Comment: rs, well, in the end the 0s was exactly the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "no parallel" function `fS()` calculates values into local variable which does not go anywhere, where  `fs_N()` do calculation on it's arguments. So when optimization enabled compiler eliminates all code for `fS()` as it does not affect anything. You need to store that result somewhere (probably return for that function and maybe print it out later):

```
double fS(void){
    double sum;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        sum += sin(i*0.1);
    }
//  cout << endl << sum << endl;    
    return sum;
}
```